# Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method

Tags: java, android, maven

I am trying to make an chat application with atmosphere framework.For this adding dependency I am using maven dependency.
The problem is whenever I try to compile project with maven dependency library included,It is giving error as "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1" if remove the library project runs but it gives above mentioned exception.

Here is my code.

```
  public class ListenerService extends Service
   {
    private String serverIpAddress ="someIp";

    private AtmosphereClient client;

    private final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();//Exception comes here

    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Message";

    RequestBuilder request;

    public ListenerService()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Service", "Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        PrefernceHelper prefernceHelper = new PrefernceHelper(this);
        String id = prefernceHelper.getPrefernce("OWNERID");
        Log.d("Service", "Id to be listened is " + id);
        startListening(id);

    }

    public void startListening(String channel)
    {
        Log.d("Service", "Inside Strat listening");
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient(AtmosphereClient.class);
        Log.d("Service", "Listening on " + channel);
        request = client.newRequestBuilder().method(Request.METHOD.GET).uri(serverIpAddress + "/pubsub/" + channel)
                .trackMessageLength(true)

                .encoder(new Encoder<Message, String>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public String encode(Message data)
                    {
                        Log.d("Service", "Inside encode" + data.toString());
                        try
                        {
                            return mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }).decoder(new Decoder<String, Message>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public Message decode(Event type, String data)
                    {
                        Log.d("Service", "Inside decode" + data.toString());
                        data = data.trim();

                        // Padding if (data.length() == 0) { return null; }

                        if (type.equals(Event.MESSAGE))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                return mapper.readValue(data, Message.class);
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                })

                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET);

        final org.atmosphere.wasync.Socket socket = client.create();
        socket.on("message", new Function<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public void on(final String message)
            {
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        String id = "";
                        String receviedMessage = "";
                        if (message != "")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
                                id = json.getString("from_id");
                                receviedMessage = json.getString("message");
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Log.d("Service", message);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra("id", id);
                            intent.putExtra("message", receviedMessage);
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        try
        {
            socket.on(new Function<Throwable>()
            {

                @Override
                public void on(Throwable t)
                {

                }

            }).open(request.build());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.inscripts.chatproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>chatproject</name>
    <url>http://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:Atmosphere/wasync.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:Atmosphere/wasync.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync</url>
    </scm>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>wasync</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>${ahc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>nettosphere</artifactId>
            <version>${nettosphere.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atmosphere.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.2</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
                        <platform>8</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${source.property}</source>
                    <target>${target.property}</target>
                    <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>${surefire.redirectTestOutputToFile}</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/META-INF</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/works</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/overlays</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.log</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <maxmemory>1g</maxmemory>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/docs/api/</link>
                        <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>project-team</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org-snapshot</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
            <name>Sonatype Release</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</name>
            <url>${distMgmtSnapshotsUrl}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <properties>
        <distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>
        <surefire.redirectTestOutputToFile>false</surefire.redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <source.property>1.6</source.property>
        <target.property>1.6</target.property>
        <atmosphere.version>2.0.0.RC3</atmosphere.version>
        <nettosphere.version>2.0.0.RC4</nettosphere.version>
        <ahc.version>1.7.19</ahc.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: You should create a sample application with an empty pom.xml and just a function calling the org.codehaus.jackson.map library, then add the library line in the pom.xml and post the error. That's called posting a SSCCE.

Comment: I guess this is somewhat SSCCE only.It is small part of my code.The part which is using maven is posted.No other code is using maven library.

Answer (score 0):

"conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1"
This error come from your class does not support dalvik (Android JVM)

If you don't care just use json standard lib

Comment: I want to make use of maven libraries.so i will need them.